# How define class and interface hierarchy?

Tags: java

I am confused about how to define classes and interfaces hierarchy for below scenario.

Below are the interfaces

```
public interface Save {
    public void save(List<Object> pojoList);
    public void save(String query);
} 

public interface Update {
    public void update(List<Object> pojoList, List<String> conditionList);
    public void update(String query);
} 

public interface Delete {
    public void delete(String query);
}
```

And here are the classes :

```
Class DbOperations {
}

class SaveOperation extends DbOperations implements Save {
}

class UpdateOperation extends DbOperations implements Update {
}
```

So my concerns are:

1. I want call SaveOperation, DeleteOpration class methods using instance of DbOperations (base class)
2. can you tell me which class should be which interface?
3. any modification for above hierarchy??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you confirm if your DbOperations does have something to inherit?

Comment: Yes, its contains some protected method like get db connection so i want to reuse that connection. and also any operation related db is Dboepration so i decided Dboperation as a base class and i want use saveOperation class methods .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get by having an interface implemented by multiple classes is that you can define a method that takes the interface as parameter and calls one of its methods, then the result of that call would depend on the actual type of that interface at runtime.

That said, I don't see any advantage in defining an interface DbOperation that doesn't define any method its classes will inherit.

If you have reasons to do so (it's possible, if the code you wrote is just a simplification of your scenario), from a semantical point of view I would find more meaningful having `DbOperations` as the root interface of the hierarchy, and `Save`, `Update` and `Delete` as abstract classes (or interfaces) between the actual classes and the root:

```
public interface DbOperation {
    public String thisOperation();
}

public abstract class Save implements DbOperation {
    public String thisOperation(){
        return "Save";
    }

    public void save(List<Object> pojoList);
    public void save(String query);
} 

public abstract class Update implements DbOperation{
    public String thisOperation(){
        return "Update";
    }

    public void update(List<Object> pojoList, List<String> conditionList);
    public void update(String query);
} 

public abstract class Delete implements DbOperation {
    public String thisOperation(){
        return "Delete";
    }

    public void delete(String query);
} 

class SaveOperation implements Save {
}

class UpdateOperation implements Update {
}
```

Comment: How do you assume his DbOperations doesn't have methods to inherit?

Comment: @pulp_fiction Because OP wrote none in it. I also specified that if there are, and the that code is just a simplified version of the actual one, I would just do a slight modification.

Comment: That might very well be, "does not want to expose proprietary/private API " thing. I mean, it is base class for some reason.

Comment: @pulp_fiction you're totally right, that's why I wrote "If you have reasons to do so (it's possible, if the code you wrote is just a simplification of your scenario)". If the structure *has* be like that, why is he asking? And why taking away from the code relevant parts?

Comment: @pulp_fiction You are absolutely correct i  does not want to expose proprietary/private API .....

Answer (score 0):

So regarding your concern,

> I want call SaveOperation, DeleteOpration class methods using instance
>   of DbOperations (base class)

I think, it will go something like this:

```
DbOperations op = new SaveOperation(/*Params*/);

// Check type to cast
if(op instanceof Save)
{
    // Cast to Save and call method
    ((Save)op).save(/*Params*/);
}

// For delete
if(op instanceof Delete)
{
    // Cast to Save and call method
    ((Delete)op).delete(/*Params*/);
}
```

So, you don't need any modification.